# Where is the "Vary for traits" button in Xcode 13?

Tags: xcode, ide

The new canvas bottom bar is more compact and the device selector now shows as a pop-over, but the "Vary for traits" button isn't there anymore.
I tried every menu of the canvas, with and without the option key, to no avail.
Also the Xcode Help is really old and does not give any clue about it.
Where can I find it?